# ROS Answers SE migration: rosserial wire

Tags: rosserial, ros-hydro, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I can't seem to be able to use Wire.h in arduino with the rosserial library. Each time I try, I get this message :

```
 [WARN] [WallTime: 1395811454.890221] Serial Port read returned short (expected 1 bytes, received 0 instead).
 [WARN] [WallTime: 1395811454.891349] Serial Port read failure: 
 [ERROR] [WallTime: 1395803426.139769] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

I admit, I have both groovy and hydro on my computer but I installed the ros library using  rosserial in groovy with grovvy sourced and right now I'm using groovy and not hydro. Here are all the source and command I use on setup :

```
alias groovy='source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash && source /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash && export EDITOR='nano' && export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/ros/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks'
```

Hydro is thus not a factor and if I remove Wire.h from my arduino project the connection is successful and I can publish data.

Any help in order to help sove this problem will be appreciate and rewarded with... heu... love <3.
Thanks a lot.

[EDIT for the comments]

@billtecteacher What I mean is, for the error to be appear I have to had `#include <Wire.h>` at the begin of the code

@balto I rebuild the ros_lib for groovy using

```
 cd <sketchbook>/libraries
 rm -rf ros_lib
 rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144366/rosserial-wire/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on 2014-03-25**:
what do you mean by adding wire and taking it out.  Wondering if it the code associated with wire that is causing the problem and not wire.h?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-03-25**:
Do you rebuild the ros_lib for groovy?

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-25**:
I edited the question to answer those questions.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-03-26**:
I use the Arduino Wire library with rosserial so I do not believe that is the error.  Can you check the code on the Arduino?

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-26**:
Well I ran in another problem and I suppressed hydro and reinstall groovy. I'll try reinstall rosserial_arduino and I'll tell if I still have that problem.
But the code works fine without #include "Wire.h" and doesn't work with it. And it is the simplest publisher possible. I use nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I redid a fresh install of rosserial and used `git checkout groovy-devel` after the `git clone` command. I don't exactly know if that's what did the trick but it's working now.

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1